# How to pass data between activities on Android with SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to save and load game score from activity 1 (SummaryActivity.java) to activity 2 (LevelSelect.java).
So some button will visible when some score reached.
I try this method but doesn't work.

**How to implement SharedPreferences for this different activities?**

SummaryActivity.java is a class when finished playing the game.

I used **int result** for pass data from **SummaryActivity.java** to **LevelSelect.java** and not work.

I want to send this score to other activity (LevelSelect.java) with SharedPreferences, so I can make some level with buttons.

Default buttons for level 2 until level 10 are invisible (gone), and after score reached more than 700 pts, I want to make that buttons visible. So player can play with higher level.

But, when i change **result** to **800** (with number), this code is work well. I don't know why **result** not work.

That **result** not save the score. But work fine if I used Google Leaderboard.

**This is SummaryActivity.java:**

```
int result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.summary);

    SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=saved_values.edit();
         editor.putInt("level1", result);
         editor.apply();
mclient = getApiClient();

    if(mclient.isConnected())
       {
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),
         getString(R.string.leaderboard_level_1),
         result); // this result is work

       }
}

private void displaySummary()
{
    String summary = getString(R.string.answered)
            + " " + mCorrectAnswers
            + " " + getString(R.string.of)
            + " " + mTotalQuestions
            + " " + getString(R.string.questions_correctly);

    mSummaryText.setText(summary);

    int score = (int)(((double)mCorrectAnswers / (double)mTotalQuestions) * 1000); // this is score

    result = (score);

    mScoreText.setText(score + ""); 
    }
```

**This is LevelSelect.java:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.levelselect);

    SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    count = saved_values.getInt("level1", 0);

    // This button is not visible by default.
    // I want to make it visible when result score reached 700 pts
    Button level2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level2Button);
    level2Button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound.playButtonSelect();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),L2_MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    if (count > 700)
    {
        level2Button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

**This is for the button:**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/level2Button"
        style="@style/FeedbackButton"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/level2" />
```

**SOLVED. This is my new SummaryActivity.java:**

```
int result;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.summary);


mclient = getApiClient();

    if(mclient.isConnected())
       {
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),
         getString(R.string.leaderboard_level_1),
         result); // this result is work

       }
}

private void displaySummary()
{
    String summary = getString(R.string.answered)
            + " " + mCorrectAnswers
            + " " + getString(R.string.of)
            + " " + mTotalQuestions
            + " " + getString(R.string.questions_correctly);

    mSummaryText.setText(summary);

    int score = (int)(((double)mCorrectAnswers / (double)mTotalQuestions) * 1000); // this is score

    result = (score);

    mScoreText.setText(score + ""); 

SharedPreferences saved_values = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=saved_values.edit();
         editor.putInt("level1", result);
         editor.apply();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int myIntValue = sp.getInt("result", 0);
```

To

```
int myIntValue = sp.getInt("level1", 0);
```

Comment: Hi @uguboz, I try but not work. The button still gone when i reached 700 pts.

Comment: Try Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "result is "+ myIntValue); and see if it is true

Comment: And your if condition is >700 not >=700

Comment: Yes, my condition is > 700. I was update my quewstion.

Comment: first why do you use sharedpref editor when result is null? u should use sharedpref editor after u set result everytime. so the sharedpref can update its value with uptodate result value.

Comment: Thanks very much @uguboz, I solve this problem. You save me. I was think sharedpreferences must below onCreate, but its not.